# Migration yaml - A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value

Tags: migrations

I think I might be losing myself here. I am getting an invalid YAML error on a very simple migration file that really should be working fine. Would someone mind taking a look and letting me know if they can see something obvious that I am missing? Error code is:

```
A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value at line 14 (near "  method: row").
```

YAML file is:

```
id: data
label: 'Data'
source:
  plugin: data
  key: migrate
process:
  name: data
    -
      plugin: existing_term
      vocabulary: data_source
      source: data
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:taxonomy_term'
  default_bundle: data_source
```

Migration runs without error if I remove process plugins underneath name. Same error occurs if I get rid of the second process plugin (so with no piping). Basically, if I add anything that is indented more than 1 level, this error throws. I am sure that indention is '2 spaces', and this structure has worked in the past. This is on a vanilla drupal 9 install done with composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the details of the YAML content, but just looking at the YAML it seems to me that `name: data` should be just `name:` otherwise it is not valid YAML.

Comment: it actually should be replaced with `type:`

Comment: OMG. yeah. I forgot to delete that when I added in the process plugins.